# magnitude of vector in algebra

Tags: vectors, roots

I am trying to solve the following equation for x, in plain algebra this was easy

$ y  = x - \frac{1}{ x} $

$ x^{2} - yx - 1 = 0 $

$ x = \frac{-y  \pm \sqrt (y^{2} + 4)}{2} $

However, throwing arrows on top of this solution leads to a nonsense result. attempting to do this with vectors has me confused

$ \vec y  = \vec x - \frac{\vec x}{||\vec x ||^{2}}$

$ \vec y ||\vec x ||^{2} = \vec x ||\vec x ||^{2} - \vec x$

what do I do with the magnitude of the unknown vector?

Comment: $\vec y$ is a scalar multiple of $\vec x$, so if you’re trying to find the latter, you just need to find that scalar. That is, the magnitude of the unknown vector is more or less what you’re trying to solve for.

Comment: doh! you're right. Transpose as an answer and I will accept it as the most helpful answer. $ ||x|| = \frac{-||y||  \pm \sqrt (||y||^{2} + 4)}{2} $, $\vec x = \vec y * ||x||$

Comment: @amd the OP has aked you to post your comment as an answer. He did not start the message with at amd

Comment: @WillJagy Already done, but thanks!

Comment: @amd I see what you mean.

Comment: correction on my comment, $ \vec x = \vec y * \frac{||\vec x||}{||\vec y||}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\vec x$ is a scalar multiple of $\vec y$, so you really just need to find their relative magnitudes, i.e., solve for $\|x\|$ in terms of $\|y\|$. That leads right back to your original equation and solution.

Answer (score 1):

It might help if you introduce a new unit vector
$$ \vec{u} = \frac{\vec{x}}{|\vec{x}|}  $$

Then we make real coefficients, 
$$ \vec{x} = x \; \vec{u}, $$
$$ \vec{y} = y \;  \vec{u}. $$ 
This means we have chosen $x = |\vec x|$

Next, you wanted
$$ \vec y  = \vec x - \frac{\vec x}{||\vec x ||^{2}},$$
$$ y \vec u  = x \; \vec u - \frac{ x \;\vec u}{x^{2}},$$
$$ y \; \vec u  = \left(x - \frac{1}{x} \right) \; \vec u .$$
$$ y   = \left(x - \frac{1}{x} \right)  .$$

Comment: do you have  an idea for how to use this transformation to find $\vec x$ I tried to use $y = \vec y \dot \vec u $ as  a substitution in $ x = \frac{-y  \pm \sqrt (y^{2} + 4)}{2} $ but got nowhere